# Getting a Syntax Error in python with first program

Tags: python, python-idle

So, I'm just starting to try to learn Python and I'm following a "book" called: *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python*.  I'm doing the first program in the book and I thought things were going just fine...but now I'm getting an error and I'm unable to figure out why.

```
# This Program says hello and ask for my name.

print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?') # ask fo their name
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName)
print('What is your age?') # ask for thier age
myAge = input()
print('You will be ' +str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

VS Code shows errors starting around line 9 but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Missing `)` in `print(len(myName)`

Comment: Missing `)` at line no 8, `print(len(myName))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(len(myName)`
Missing ')'.